# Is it possible to speed-up conversion of a list into an array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, list

In my code, I have noticed that the conversion of a list into an array takes a significant amount of time.

I'm wondering if there any faster ways on how to convert a list to an array in python, here are my three attempts:

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import  timeit
from array import array


added_data = range(100000)

def test1():
    np.asarray(added_data, dtype=np.float16)

def test2():
    np.array(added_data, dtype=np.float16)

def test3():
    array('f', added_data)

print(timeit(test1,number=100))
print(timeit(test2,number=100))
print(timeit(test3,number=100))
```

In other words:

**Input:** < type 'list' >

**Output:** < type 'array.array' >

Comment: `numpy` module has `arange(...)` function. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very unlikely that there's a faster way to convert a list of values into an array than the obvious and simple approaches you've already tried. If there was a better way, the `numpy` authors probably would have implemented it in `np.asarray` or the `np.array` constructor itself. I also want to note that `array.array` creates a much less sophisticated object than the `numpy` functions, so it's probably not what you want.

What you might be able to do to improve your program's overall performance is to avoid creating the list in the first place. Perhaps you can read external data from a file directly into an array with `np.loadtxt` or `np.load` (depending on how it is formatted). Or maybe you can generate the array from scratch with functions like `np.arange`, rather than using a normal Python function like `range` that (in Python 2) returns a list.

Answer (score 1):

It gonna be the same result:

```
from array import array
def test4() :
    array = array('d')
    for item in added_data: # comma, or other
        array.append(item)
```

But you can try:

```
from array import array
def test5() :
    dataset_array = array('d')
    dataset_array.extend(added_data)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Your metod would create <type 'list'> , however I'm looking for <type 'array.array'>.

Comment: You are right. After change to array it seems to have a worse time.

Answer (score 0):

Adding item into numpy array will make performance issues. Never do that.

Alternatives:
1- Adding items into list and convert that list into numpy array.

2- use deque from collections. This is the best way.

```
import collections
a = collections.deque([1,2,3,4])
a.append(5)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it doesn't answer my question.